# Slice append from channels

Tags: go

I want to create slice and add values returned from channel. 
Below is the code I tried but could not able to solve it.

I have to send address of the slice, but I am not able to figure out how :(

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func sendvalues(cs chan int){
    for i:=0;i<10;i++{
        cs<-i   
    }   
}

func appendInt(cs chan int, aINt []int)[]*int{
    for {
        select {
        case i := <-cs:
            aINt = append(aINt,i)//append returns new type right ?
            fmt.Println("slice",aINt)
        }   
    }   
}



func main() {
    cs := make(chan int)
    intSlice := make([]int, 0,10)

    fmt.Println("Before",intSlice)
    go sendvalues(cs)
    go appendInt(cs,intSlice)// I have to pass address here

    time.Sleep(999*999999)
    fmt.Println("After",intSlice)
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code won't work for two (in fact three) reasons:

1. `append` returns a new slice as soon as the capacity is reached.
   Thus, the assignment in `appendInt` will do nothing.
2. `appendInt` runs concurrently, therefore:

   - As long as `appendInt` does not message `main` that it is finished, 
     `main` does not know when the `intSlice` has all the values you want.
   - You have to wait for all goroutines to return at the end of `main`

#### Problem 1: Modifying slices in functions

You may know that in Go every value you pass to a function is copied. Reference values,
such as slices, are copied too, but have pointers internally which then point to the original memory location. That means you can modify the elements of a slice in a function. What you 
can't do is reassigning this value with a new slice as the internal pointer would point to somewhere different. **You need pointers for that**. Example ([Play](http://play.golang.org/p/9_GkY6WLi1)):

```
func modify(s *[]int) {
    for i:=0; i < 10; i++ {
        *s = append(*s, i)
    }
}

func main() {
    s := []int{1,2,3}
    modify(&s)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

#### Problem 2: Synchronizing goroutines

To wait for started goroutines, you can use a [`sync.WaitGroup`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup). Example ([Play](http://play.golang.org/p/LIh-CAuShF)):

```
func modify(wg *sync.WaitGroup, s *[]int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i:=0; i < 10; i++ {
        *s = append(*s, i)
    }
}

func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    s := []int{1,2,3}

    wg.Add(1)
    go modify(wg, &s)

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

The example above waits (using `wg.Wait()`) for `modify` to finish 
(`modify` calls `wg.Done()` when finished). If you remove the `wg.Wait()` call, you will
see why not synchronizing is a problem. Comparison of outputs:

- With `wg.Wait()`: `[1 2 3 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]`
- Without `wg.Wait()`: `[1 2 3]`

The main goroutine returns earlier than the `modify` goroutine which is why you will never
see the modified results. Therefore **synchronizing is absolutely necessary**.

A good way to communicate the new slice would be to use a channel. You would not need to 
use pointers and you would have synchronization. Example ([Play](http://play.golang.org/p/tEaASoDPv0)):

```
func modify(res chan []int) {
    s := []int{}
    for i:=0; i < 10; i++ {
        s = append(s, i)
    }
    res <- s
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan []int)
    go modify(c)

    s := <-c
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```